# How to use v-for to dynamically display data table with nested loops

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a table component called from my entry file. The Table component gets the `documents` object passed on as prop. Inside the table component I have a table which should render the object data one under another in order the data comes in. Each row should have the `User name`, `Document name`, and `date of view`. (Please see bottom of the question for current & expected result). I am facing the issue because the object is structured in a way that the `views` are nested inside the `parent`, and I don't know how to loop over the outer object to get into the inner one without affecting the layout (Hence the use of `<span>`)

Object:

```
data() {
    return {
      documents: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Doc 1",
          date: "01.01.1995",
          doc_website: "linktodocument1.com",
          views: [
            {
              id: 4,
              user_name: "Jon",
              doc_id: 1,
              view_date: "01.02.1996",
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              user_name: "Bob",
              doc_id: 1,
              view_date: "05.02.1996",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Doc 2",
          date: "01.01.2000",
          doc_website: "linktodocument2.com",
          views: [
            {
              id: 1,
              user_name: "Bob",
              doc_id: 2,
              view_date: "01.02.1996",
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              user_name: "Jon",
              doc_id: 2,
              view_date: "05.02.1996",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Doc 3",
          date: "01.01.2000",
          doc_website: "linktodocument3.com",
          views: [
            {
              id: 1,
              user_name: "Bob",
              doc_id: 3,
              view_date: "01.02.1996",
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              user_name: "Jon",
              doc_id: 3,
              view_date: "05.02.1996",
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              user_name: "Rob",
              doc_id: 3,
              view_date: "05.02.1996",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Entry File:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Document</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <table-component :docObject="documents"></table-component>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import tableComponent from "./table.vue";

export default {
  components: { tableComponent },
}
</script>
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <tbody>
    <span v-for="doc in docObject" :key="doc.name">
      <td v-for="view in doc.views" :key="view.id">
        <p>
          {{ view.user_name }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>
          {{ doc.name }}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td v-for="view in doc.views" :key="view.name">
        <p>
          {{ view.view_date }}
        </p>
      </td>
    </span>
  </tbody>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: ["docObject"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
td {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

```
Current Output: 
Name                                                   Document Date      
Jon Bob Doc 1 1.02.1996 05.02.1996
Bob Jon Doc 2 01.02.1996 05.02.1996
Bob Jon Rob Doc 3 01.02.1996 05.02.1996 05.02.1996

Expected Result:
Name             Document           Date
Jon               Doc 1            1.02.1996
Bob               Doc 1            05.02.1996
Bob               Doc 2            01.02.1996
Bob               Doc 2            05.02.1996
Bob               Doc 3            01.02.1996
Jon               Doc 3            05.02.1996
Rob               Doc 3            05.02.1996
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cerf-rfmf2?file=/src/components/table.vue:0-585

Comment: Couldn't you use [tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) instead of `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `template` instead of `span` and there is no need to complicate it further with multiple `td` tags, it can be simple as this:

```
<template>
  <tbody>
    <template v-for="doc in docObject">
      <tr v-for="view in doc.views" :key="view.id">
        <td>{{ view.user_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ doc.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ view.view_date }}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: ["docObject"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
td {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Please check this codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ives-b33u5?file=/src/components/table.vue

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I was under impression that `<template>` was vue reserved syntax. I will need to look into it further. Thanks again!